# update a table from another table and add new values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I go about updating a table by using another table so it puts in the new data and if it doesnt match on an id it adds the new id and the data with it. My original table i much bigger than the new table that will update it. and the new table has a few ids that aren't in the old table but need to be added.

for example I have:
Table being updated-

```
  +-------------------+
  |  Original Table   |
  +-------------------+
  |  ID  |  Initials  |
  |------+------------|
  |  1   |  ABC       |
  |  2   |  DEF       |
  |  3   |  GHI       |
```

and...
the table I'm pulling data from to update the other table-

```
  +-------------------+
  |    New Table      |
  +-------------------+
  |  ID  |  Initials  |
  |------+------------|
  |  1   |  XZY       |
  |  2   |  QRS       |
  |  3   |  GHI       |
  |  4   |  ABC       |
```

then I want my Original table to get its values that match up to be updated by the new table if they have changed, and add any new ID rows if they aren't in the original table so in this example it would look like the New Table.

```
  +-------------------+
  |   Original Table  |
  +-------------------+
  |  ID  |  Initials  |
  |------+------------|
  |  1   |  XZY       |
  |  2   |  QRS       |
  |  3   |  GHI       |
  |  4   |  ABC       |
```

Comment: What is the sql server version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MERGE statement to put this UPSERT operation in one statement but there are issues with merge statement I would split it into two Statements, UPDATE and INSERT

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE O
SET O.Initials  = N.Initials  
FROM Original_Table O INNER JOIN New_Table N 
ON O.ID = N.ID
```

**INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO Original_Table (ID , Initials)
SELECT ID , Initials  
FROM New_Table
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                   FROM Original_Table
                   WHERE ID = Original_Table.ID)
```

*Important Note*

Reason why I suggested to avoid using merge statement read this article [`Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) by *Aaron Bertrand*

Comment: do i need to convert the New_Table values to varchar somehow? My original Table columns are varchar(6) and varchar(3) while my new table is coming from an excel sheet so it is nvarchar(255) and nvarchar(255).

Comment: No you dont need to as datatype is same its only the that your original Table can store longer strings and it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: what does it mean by this then? Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: In any case when you are inserting row from an excel or for that matter any other source other than sql server always get you data into sql server first , in a staging table, than from there insert data into your actual final destination tables. Importing data directly into your tables from outer sources is never a good idea. In your case import data into a staging table with varchar(255) column in from your excel sheet and than pull data from there to insert into your actual tables.

Comment: @M.Ali one last question... in the subquery what does the Select 1 mean exactly? I found out that it wasn't being put into my table because there was bad data.

Comment: I'm using Exists operator in the WHERE clause, which checks for true or false conditions, if there is a row to a corresponding id it returns 1, meaning true . Google EXISTS operator in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MERGE statement for this:

```
MERGE  original_table AS Target
USING updated_table as Source
ON original_table.id = updated_table.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Target.Initials = Source.Initials
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(id, Initials) VALUES(Source.id, Source.Initials);
```

You have not specified, what happens in case the valuesin original table are not found in the updated one. But, just in case, you can add this to remove them from original table:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
   THEN DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can use loop in PHP and go through all tables and copy one by one to another table.

another option

```
DECLARE @COUT INT 
SET @COUT = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM New_Table
    WHILE (true)
    BEGIN
    IF @COUT = 0
      BREAK;
SET @COUT = @COUT - 1
    DECLARE @id INT
    DECLARE @ini VARCHAR(20)
    SET @id = (SELECT id FROM New_Table);
    SET @ini = (SELECT Initials FROM New_Table);
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Original_Table WHERE id=@id ) > 0 
    UPDATE SET ID = @id,Initials = @ini FROM Original_Table WHERE id = @id;
    insert into Original_Table values(@id,@ini);
    END
    GO
```